# Multiple comment box

Tags: textbox

I have multiple comment text box in my page.User make comments to every categories.I have 13 categories.How can i make my page user friendly.

Current site
[image: Currunt site]

Accordion sample
[image: I think i can use accordion]

Comment: Are they all required? Are on the same subject, or different subjects? Are some related, and not related to others?

Comment: Its about cars.Your comments about design,performance,service quality,fuel consume ext...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your form (the long one) is simple to understand and straightforward to use, it has a couple of problems:

- The amount of questions and the length of the form feel **overwhelming**. Have you measured how long it takes an actual user to fill out the form completely? The textboxes are large, and suggest by design that you expect long elaborate answers.
- The respondent does not get a **sense of accomplishment** while working towards completion. It is difficult to see how much progress you have made and there is no reward at the end.
- The form lacks **structure**. There is no grouping, and all of the questions are equal. Answering 13 separate questions has a different feel than answering 3 groups of questions (with 4 items each).

A few things you could do to help your respondents give you feedback more easily:

- Reduce the **amount of effort** you ask: do you really need to ask all of these questions? How will the results be used? Consider reducing the number of questions (can you bring it down to 10?).
- Consider a **different question format**. Could you replace some of the questions by multiple-choice questions, or for example a slider? Many people don't like typing large amounts of text.
- Offer a clear **incentive**. What will your respondents earn by completing the form? Even if it is 'just' your gratitude, make that explicit.
- Create **more structure**. Can you group questions together? Which section headers could you use? (Consider running a quick card sort to find out what your users consider a logical grouping.)
- Use **pagination** to break the task into smaller, manageable steps.
- Show **progress**, for example with a progress bar.

The accordion solution seems better than the original (better overview, less unused whitespace), but I'm not sure that it is the best possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Accordion is one way of doing it, but in general having that many fields will have users turn around and leave. You likely want to avoid as many of those textareas and have users answer them each as required.

The other way is to have them fill in one at a time with a "next" button and an indicator of how many are left. Adding the possibility to skip or finish. Seeing a bunch of textareas or even accordions will drive users away, this will at least make it more pleasing and less daunting.

Answer (score 0):

Even someone who has enough good will towards your product to bother filling in a form for you is going to look at that daunting task and think "I'll come back to it later" (and this is your best case scenario). Problem is they rarely do. Ideally you would like to get something for all 13 categories, but you have to be realistic. If you get something on a subset of these categories, but manage to do it for a much greater number of users, this is surely better for your company / client.

I would give the user just one text box to fill in, but put suggestions at the side to prompt the user to think about the 13 different categories. For example:

We are interested in your opinions on the following:

- < icon > Performance
- < icon > Design
- < icon > Fuel Consumption
- < icon > Service Quality
- ...

I suggest that you use icons with the text because people tend to skim long lists rather than actually read them, and again, 13 categories is rather a lot.

Hopefully the user will give you 2 or 3 things, and those things will be what they actually had an opinion on, rather than filler answers just to type something in a text box.